# Free up malloced char * in a vector?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, malloc, free

We are given:

```
typedef const char* V;
typedef std::vector<V> Record;
```

We instantiate the record somewhere in code like:

```
Record rec;
```

We populate it with data via malloc:

```
void fixed_len_read(void *buf, int size, Record *record){
    char *c_buf = (char *)malloc(size);
    memcpy(c_buf, buf, size);
    record->push_back(c_buf);
}
```

Now after usage, I wish to free the memory allocated. Would it go away on it's own? Or would I have to free() every element?
I tried to call free like this:

```
for (int i =0; i < 100; i++) {
   free(record.at(i));
}
```

But it complains about const char.

```
    " error: no matching function for call to 'free'
    free(record.at(i));"
```

I then used a cast:

```
  for (int i =0; i < 100; i++) {
      free((char *) record.at(i));
  }
```

Now it seems to run, but I'm not sure if it works? Does that look right?

**[EDIT]**
As per comments and answer below. Casting it is ok. An alternative is to use delete() as per:
[Unable to free const pointers in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819535/unable-to-free-const-pointers-in-c)
(C's free has an issue, which was fixed in delete() in c++).

Comment: Every body is new to language C/C++. Please use one tag .

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. This is C++. Whatever you `malloc`, has to be `free`'d. It won't go away on its own. Is there a reason you cannot just use `std::vector<std::string>`? Then you don't need to worry about any of this.

Comment: Code was given by our professor. It is odd that he mixes C and C++ like this.

Comment: Very odd. Is there a special reason he wants you to learn how to write code that is error prone and difficult to maintain?

Comment: I'm asking myself the same question :-|, it's a horrible assignment. I've asked the prof if we can use strings instead.

Comment: It's not just error prone and difficult to maintain, it's complete nonsense. I wouldn't take too much from this professor.

Comment: In any case *"it complains about const char"* - you need to share the error message.

Comment: @NeilKirk I added error msg above. No matching 'free' call.

Comment: This may be because record.at(i) returns a const char * ?

Comment: Find a new professor.

Comment: Mmm... maybe we need AssignmentReview.SE on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Hm it does look like `free` cannot delete `const char *` without casting, which I didn't know about nor do I understand why. You'd be better off asking the question with just the sample code such as: http://ideone.com/wk6xfs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33622382/why-cant-free-work-with-const-pointers

Comment: @NeilKirk That makes sense, thank you for the link!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing (I'm pretty sure) is technically allowed. However, it really makes no sense to `malloc` a `const char*`, as you wouldn't be able to initialize the memory after allocation without a cast.

`free` takes a `void*`, which is why the compiler complains when you pass it a `const char*`. `const` pointers are not implicitly convertible to `void*`. When you cast away the `const`ness using `(char*)`, you make it convertible, and `free` can take the variable.

To answer your question, yes, you do need to free each element before the `vector` is destroyed. It won't happen on it's own.

Truth be told, the code your professor is giving you is complete nonsense.  If you're talking about binary data, perhaps you should be using `std::vector<std::vector<std::uint8_t>>` rather than `vector<const char*>`. If you're really holding strings, `std::vector<std::string>` makes more sense. This way, the memory is automatically free'd for you, because the container's destructors take care of it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The only thing, we don't malloc a const char. We malloc a char *?

Comment: Right, you malloc a `char*`, but then almost immediately assign it `const char*` by pushing it into the vector. That's fine, but you need to cast it back before you can free it.

Comment: Ok, that seems to make sense.