# Why can't free work with const pointers?

Tags: c++

Consider:

```
int main()
{
    const char *p = new const char[10]();
    delete[] p;
}
```

No problems here.

Now consider:

```
int main()
{
    const char *p = static_cast<const char *>(calloc(10, 1));
    free(p);
}
```

Error:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:6:8: error: invalid conversion from 'const void*' to 'void*' [-fpermissive]
  free(p);
```

http://ideone.com/tyK7Ce

Any reason you can't do this?

In practice, you might allocate non-const but when you want to delete it, you may have only a `const char *` pointer left to do it with. `delete[]` lets you do it, but not `free`. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: `const char *p` is a non-constant pointer to `const` memory.  You can't write to the memory, but there is no problem `delete`'ing it (as long as it was `new`'ed). `new` and `delete` are part of the C++ language, the compiler knows that `delete` will not write to the memory, only free it. `free()`, on the other hand, is just a function like any other, and it is not declared to accept a const pointer as input, so you can't pass a `const` pointer to it.

Comment: `free()` is a C function, not C++. Although in any case it would be odd to declare the object as const at the point of creation since that obviously makes it impossible to modify. `char* const;` on the other hand is fine, but obviously isn't the same as it makes the pointer constant, not the values within - though that has the benefit of ensuring that you can't mangle the address and pass `free()` a bad address.

Comment: @RemyLebeau But free could be declared to take `const void *`

Comment: @Olipro `free()` is a function that exists in both C and C++.

Comment: @NeilKirk: per the C standards, `free()` is formally defined as taking a non-const `void*` pointer as input. All vendor implementations follow that definition.