# Why does `NSString` `initWithBytesNoCopy` take `void *` instead of `const void *`

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have a `const char *` (or `const string&`), and I would like to append a subsection of it to an `NSMutableString`.

I figured that I could do

```
// s: const char *
// start, end: size_t
[anNSMutableString appendString:[[NSString alloc] 
    initWithBytesNoCopy:s+start
                 length:end-start  
               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
           freeWhenDone:NO]];
```

This doesn't work because `initWithBytesNoCopy` of `NSString` takes a `void *` per Apple documentation:

```
- (instancetype)initWithBytesNoCopy:(void *)bytes 
                             length:(NSUInteger)len 
                           encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding 
                       freeWhenDone:(BOOL)freeBuffer;
```

On the other hand, `initWithBytes` takes a `const void *`. Therefore, the above code works if I change it to use `initWithBytes`.

Question: Why does `NSString` `initWithBytesNoCopy` take `void *` instead of `const void *`?

Here is my thought process:

- I assume there is a valid reason that `initWithBytesNoCopy` is declared to take `void *` instead of `const void *`.
- The only valid reason I can think of is that `initWithBytesNoCopy` may modifies `bytes`, or future operations on the newly created `NSString` may modify its content.

  - However, I don't see how/why `initWithBytesNoCopy` would modify `bytes`
  - I also don't see how operation on `NSString` can modify its contents because `NSString` is immutable.
- Dead end. What did I get wrong?

Comment: I suspect because when `freeWhenDone` is YES, it will have to pass the pointer to `free(void*)`.

Comment: @jtbandes, I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819535/unable-to-free-const-pointers-in-c after reading your comment. It looks like it is a contested topic whether operations like free should take `void *` or `const void *`. It's also inconsistent in practice: `free` is defined to take `void *` whereas `delete const_ptr` is allowed. As a result, your suspicion seems plausible.