# small c program basic.returning a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I always have this doubt in mind. Please see the below program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char * function1(void);
int main()
{
    char *ch;
    ch = function1();
    printf("hello");
    free(ch);
    return 0;
}

char* function1()
{
    char *temp;
    temp = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    return temp;
}
```

am i leaking the memory here?
the program does not crash in ideone with some warnings:

```
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:11: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘free’
prog.c:11: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘free’
prog.c: In function ‘function1’:
prog.c:19: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘malloc’
prog.c:19: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’
```

and prints hello.

I am just a beginner in C.so please help me understand what happens after the return statement in function1.does free really frees the memory allocated in funtion1?

Comment: Your code my be in error because of 1) cast the return value of malloc; 2) failure to include the proper header. In this specific case, the compiler assumes `malloc` returns an int, converts that `int` to a `char*` because of the cast (**and doesn't complain which is the error**) then assign the converted value to the `temp` object. The conversion from `int` to `char*` is an error. The compiler would have caught it without the cast and with `#include <stdlib.h>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Memory leaking

You are code isn't leaking any memory because you do `free(ch);` which `free`'s memory allocated by  the `malloc` inside the `function1` function.
You can check this by printing the pointer addresses, i.e.:

```
char* function1()
{
  char *temp;
  temp=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
  printf("temp: %p\n", temp);
  return temp;
}
```

and

```
ch = function1();
printf("ch: %p\n", ch);
```

You should see that both prints (`ch` and `temp`) will print the same address. Thus, `free(ch);` will `free` the correct `malloc`ed chunk of memory.

You can use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) too check if your code doesn't `free` allocated memory.

#### About the warnings

Functions `free`, `malloc` are defined at `stdlib.h`.

Add this in your code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
...
```

Also, it's not such a good idea to cast `malloc` return value `temp=(char *)malloc(...);`.
Have a read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953112/should-i-explicitly-cast-mallocs-return-value).

Comment: i understand your answer..but my question is whether its leaking the memory or not?

Comment: as u said i have added the stdlib.h.the warnings are gone now.but what is happening after the return statement?

Comment: @Luzhin: Why do you want him to add stdio.h twice. That's just not required because he already has it in his code. Has the implementation of C changed?

Comment: @Programmer ... I don't want him to add stdio.h twice. Why are you saying this?

Comment: My doubt is when i return temp.temp is local to the function1 and it becomes out of scope.so does the address of the memory allocated is safely passed to the main and safely freed or not?

Comment: @vijay: yes it is safely passed and freed as you have the address to  the data

Comment: @Luzhin: in your asnwer u tell him to add stdio.h when he already has that

Comment: on x86 architectures the return value of a function is usually returned in the eax register (except for floating point numbers); once the content of the memory location which holds the pointer given by malloc gets "copied" into eax, the stack frame of the function can safely go away. you're returning the value kept in temp, not the address of temp (this would be an error).

Answer (score 2):

You need to include `stdlib.h` to use `free` and `malloc`.

It just happens to not matter what `free` and `malloc` actually do in your code above, so it still works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, free frees the memory allocated in function 1 and gives it back to the free memory pool so that it can be reused. this is important because if you dont free memory you can reach in a situtation where your RAM is full and calls to malloc fail.

Do include stdlib.h as it contains definition for malloc.

Also, if you use free, you are not leaking memory

Answer (score 0):

Suggested alternative:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

char * function1(void);

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *ch = function1();
  if (!ch)
    printf("ERROR: Unable to allocate memory!\n");
  else
  {
    printf("Allocation successful.\n");
    free(ch);
  }
  return 0;
}

char*
function1()
{
  return (char *)malloc(10);
}
```

Compile:

> gcc -Wall -pedantic -o x x.c (where "x.c" is the source file, and "x" the .exe)