# Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value(s) - C valgrind

Tags: c, valgrind

I got this error: 
==4024== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4024==    at 0x400D69: constructBoardSpaces (in /a/fr-01/vol/home/stud/roniy02/oop/Ex3/Play)

and the function is:

```
static void constructBoardSpaces(char** array,int rows,int cols)
{
    int i=0,j=0;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
        {
            if((array[i][j])!='X'&&(array[i][j]!='O'))
                {
                array[i][j]=' ';
                }
        }
    }
}
```

can't figure out what is the problem.
Thanks

Comment: Sounds familiar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089892/conditional-jump-or-move-depends-on-uninitialised-values/7089919#7089919

Comment: If you compile with the `-g` flag, then Valgrind will be able to tell you the precise line number of the code that has the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure you initialized the two dimensional array before you enter that loop? Otherwise I would say the problem is probably in the if statement where you read from the array:

```
if((array[i][j])!='X'&&(array[i][j]!='O'))
```

Comment: @fgfjhgrjr erjhm : When you ask a question and manage to get it solved, do try to post the answer/solution. Its not clear in this case, what exactly was  the problem and what fixed it.

Comment: Request you to accept the answer if it solved your problem. This will help other readers.