# variable length array of fixed length arrays in C

Tags: c

I have a function that accepts a variable length array of 80 character strings. I defined the function like so:

```
void foo (char namelist[][80] ...
```

in main() I do the following:

```
char **names = (char **)malloc(numNames * 80);
foo(names);
```

The type of names here is not correct. What is the appropriate way to type it as a variable length array of fixed length arrays?

Comment: You should not cast the return value of malloc in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`names` should be declared as:

```
char (*names)[80];
```

This declares `names` as a pointer to an array of 80 chars.

By the way, there's no need to cast the return value of `malloc` in C and many people consider it bad practice. See: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953112/should-i-explicitly-cast-mallocs-return-value).

Comment: This is correct. Though I think the advantages of casting malloc outweigh the disadvantages. To cast here: `(char (*)[])`