# C extern struct pointer dynamic allocation

Tags: c, struct, malloc, extern

I'm trying to allocate dynamically a global struct in c, but something makes my c file not being able to find the reference to the extern variable.

The log:

```
main.c:18: undefined reference to `gate_array'
```

extern.h

```
#ifndef EXTERN_H_
#define EXTERN_H_


typedef struct gate_struct {
    int out;
} gate;

extern gate *gate_array;


#endif /* EXTERN_H_ */
```

main.c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include "extern.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    gate_array = (gate*) malloc (2* sizeof(gate));

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: where is `gate_array` declaration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no definition of `gate_array` due to `extern`. In this case, you can just remove the `extern` qualifier. However, if `extern.h` was used in multiple translation units (`#include` in several `.c` files) then this approach would result in multiple definition errors. Consider adding another `.c` file that would contain the definiton of `gate_array` (and any future variables), ensuring there is exactly one definition of `gate_array`.

The `extern gate *gate_array` tells the compiler that there is a variable called `gate_array`, but it is defined somewhere else. But there is no definition of `gate_array` in the posted code.

---

Also, you may wish to read
[Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Just removed the extern qualifier and the problem was solved. :) Thanks! Still don't see why you say there's no definition of gate_array as it is a "gate" struct that is defined above...

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you meant to do:

```
#ifndef EXTERN_H_
#define EXTERN_H_


typedef struct gate_struct {
    int out;
} gate;

typedef gate *gate_array;


#endif /* EXTERN_H_ */
```

This `typedefs` `gate *` to `gate_array`. Then in your `main.c` you want to do:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include "extern.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    gate_array name_of_array = malloc (2* sizeof(gate));
    free(name_of_array);

    return 0;
}
```

Previously you were missing a variable name. Furthermore, it is [bad practice to cast the return of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953112/should-i-explicitly-cast-mallocs-return-value).

Answer (score 0):

Pointer to gate i.e. `gate_array` was typedef not declared so you were doing something like this:

```
typedef int *IXX;
IXX = (int*) malloc(2*sizeof(int));
```

Do something like this:

```
IXX ix = (int*) malloc(2*sizeof(int));
```