# Necessity of use (float*) before malloc

Tags: c

In the program of any pointer variable we often use :

```
float *x;
x=(float*)malloc(a*sizeof(long int));
```

I want to know why we use `(float*)` in front of `malloc`?

Comment: See [Should I explicitly cast malloc()'s return value?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/953112/1168156)

Comment: You use it because you haven't read [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Why do you use `sizeof(long int)` for allocating an array of `float` ??

Answer (score 1):

Malloc returns a pointer to void.

`(float*)` casts from a pointer to void to a pointer to float

In C this is not necessary, in C++ it is, so some people recommend that to make your code compatible with C++ compilers.

But you don't need to do that. (and some C fans are against it)

Answer (score -2):

`malloc` will give you a pointer to `void` that you can't use for anything related to things you want to do with a `float`. To be able to use the variable allocated at the returned memory location, you need to cast it to a `float*` so you can dereference that pointer and use it as a `float`.

But, as you've written your question, you should cast the return value of `malloc` to `float*` and then immediately dereference it before assigning it to `x`, since you've not declared `x` as a pointer to `float`.

**EDIT:** As commenters pointed out, the explicit cast is only **needed** in C++, not in C.

Comment: Only true on C++, C has automatic cast.

Comment: @speeder no, C has automatic type conversion. A cast is always explicit.

Comment: Wrong name of things... But it still applies :)

Comment: @speeder: true, I didn't notice the C only tag :)