# Runtime Error with Printing Double Pointer Char Array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, double-pointer

I am working on creating a system for entering student names and scores into arrays and printing the same information to the screen, unfortunately I keep getting the weird output.

I stepped through my program using a debugger and it showed that everything runs smooth until I get to the function that prints the student's information, there the double pointer char arrays have messed up values.

Here's an image of what I see when I run the program. (http://s28.postimg.org/nv29feawt/Error.png)

*Note: Although I am aware that there are better and easier ways of doing this I am required to complete this assignment using dynamically allocated memory and arrays.*

```
int main(void)
{
    char **firstNames;
    char **lastNames;
    float *scores;

    int recordsLength;
    printf("Please indicate the number of records you want to enter: ");
    scanf("%d", &recordsLength);
    printf("\n\n");

    firstNames = (char **)malloc(recordsLength * sizeof(char *));
    lastNames = (char **)malloc(recordsLength * sizeof(char *));
    scores = (float *)malloc(recordsLength * sizeof(float));

    int i = 0;
    while(i < recordsLength)
    {
        createNewEntry(i, firstNames, lastNames, scores);
        i++;
    }

    printEntry(0, firstNames, lastNames, scores);
    free(firstNames);
    free(lastNames);
    free(scores);
    return 0;
}

void clearScreen()
{
#ifdef _WIN32 
    system("cls");
#elif _unix_ 
    system("clear");
#endif
}

void printEntry(int entryID, char *firstNames[], char *lastNames[], float scores[])
{
    clearScreen();
    printf("|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|\n");
    printf("|                           Student Entry                                 |\n");
    printf("|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|\n|\n");
    printf("|   First Name: %s   Last Name: %s   Score: %.1f\n|\n|\n|\n", firstNames[entryID], lastNames[entryID], scores[entryID]);
    printf("|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|\n");
    printf("|                                                                         |\n");
    printf("|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|\n\n");
}

void createNewEntry(int index, char *firstNames[], char *lastNames[], float scores[])
{
    printf("Please input the records of the new student.\n\n\n");
    char first[20];
    char last[20];
    float score = 100.0f;

    printf("Please enter the student's first name: ");
    scanf("%s", &first);
    printf("\n\n");

    printf("Please enter the student's last name: ");
    scanf("%s", &last);
    printf("\n\n");

    printf("Please enter the student's score: ");
    scanf("%f", &score);
    printf("\n\n");

    firstNames[index] = (char *)malloc((strlen(first)) * sizeof(char));
    firstNames[index] = first;

    lastNames[index] = (char *)malloc((strlen(last)) * sizeof(char));
    lastNames[index] = last;
    printf("first name: %s", firstNames[index]);
    printf("last name: %s", lastNames[index]);
    scores[index] = score;
}
```

Comment: Never cast the returns from malloc realloc, calloc

Comment: `firstNames[index] = first;` and `lastNames[index] = last;` look suspect. What you're doing is copying the pointer, not the array's contents.

Comment: I hope you have include `stdio.h` in your original assignment. Moreover, it would be better if you cut down your code and post a shorter version of code (minimal code that demonstrates your issue. For example a version with only firstNames and no lastNames.

Comment: you need `strcpy` from char first[20]; to firstNames[index] and so on, because wheen your returned from `createNewEntry()` your `"firstNames[index]"` becomes invalid

Comment: wheen your do this: `lastNames[index] = (char *)malloc((strlen(last)) * sizeof(char));
    lastNames[index] = last;` you simply remove your pointer, that kept in the previous row

Comment: Thank you, Ivan Ivanovich and Mohit Jain! It works like a charm now! Can I ask why I should never cast the returns from malloc realloc, and calloc?

Comment: You can read more about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953112/should-i-explicitly-cast-mallocs-return-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
firstNames[index] = (char *)malloc((strlen(first)) * sizeof(char));
firstNames[index] = first;  /* You are missing your allocated memory block and assigning local */
```

Above lines are incorrect. You can not assign `c-strings` with assignation `=` operator. You should use `strcpy` for that.

You are assigning local array to firstnames, which has no life after the function ends. This invokes an **undefined behavior**. (You are seeing the strange characters, but it can be even worse).

Should be Re-written as (Similar for last name also)

```
firstNames[index] = malloc((strlen(first) + 1) * sizeof(char)); /* +1 for \0 */
if(firstNames[index] == NULL) {
  /* Malloc failed, error handling */
  ...
}
/* else */
strcpy(firstNames[index], first);  /* Use strcpy to copy contents */
```

[Live example here](http://ideone.com/tdgWsT)

Before freeing `firstNames` and `lastNames`, you should free all the member of firstNames and lastNames in a loop.

Comment: Or you can use `firstNames[index] = strdup(first);` — if necessary, writing `strdup()`.  It is a POSIX function but not a Standard C function.  Also, the code should check that `malloc()` succeeds before using the allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer of Mohit Jain, adding to that you can even use `sprintf`.

Comment: While you could use `sprintf()` — or even `snprintf()` — it is not clear why you would want to do so.  You could use `memcpy()` or `memmove()` instead of `strcpy()` too, if you're careful to capture the length found by `strlen()` — that might be better.